# Error on constructor in derived class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, constructor

I have a parent class

```
abstract class ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassPlugin(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }
    public eGuiType GuiType;

    public void Action() { }
}
```

I want all derived classes to implement the Action member and to define the guyType field.
To do that I have put it in the constructor, this is the only way that comes to mind.
Therefore an abstract class can be:

```
class ClassStartWF: ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassStartWF(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }

    public void Action()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

the problem is that I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter '_guyType' of
>   'MainWindow.ClassPlugin.ClassPlugin(MainWindow.eGuiType)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the base class constructor in derived class constructor. Since you have create a constructor then compiler will not generate default constructor for your classes.

```
public ClassStartWF(eGuiType _guyType)
   : base(_guyType)
{
    // GuiType = _guyType; //this is not needed since the value is assigned in the base class constructor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems...

First, you need to call the base class constructor from the derived type, as the base has no default constructor:

```
public ClassStartWF(eGuiType _guyType) : base(_guyType)
{
}
```

Since the base class takes care of setting the field you don't need to do it.

Secondly, you should make `Action` abstract in the base class and then override it in the derived class:

```
abstract class ClassPlugin
{
    public abstract void Action();
}

class ClassStartWF: ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassStartWF(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }

    public override void Action()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

At the moment you calls to `Action` won't dispatch to the derived instances when called through a base reference.

Also, rather than make `GuiType` a public variable you'd be better off making it a property:

```
public eGuiType GuiType{get; set;}
```

This will give you some control over the value. Also, you might want to consider making the setter private if it should only ever be set during construction.